# How to run the terminal using keyboard shortcuts in Gnome 2?

Tags: linux, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Gnome 2. I use the terminal several times, and I lose a lot of time going in Applications / Utilities / Terminal to launch the terminal. I am wondering if I can launch the terminal using keyboard shortcuts. I would like to do something similar to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but you may like some quick-starter app such as `gnome-do`. You can bind that to a shortcut, e.g. meta+space, and then start any application by typing its name. And since I also start a terminal often, all it takes for me is, alt+space+t+enter to start terminator. Yet it also starts any application without having to bind certain tools to specific keys.

Answer (score 20):

You should go to *Settings / Keyboard / Shortcuts* and find the tab labeled *shortcuts*, then *add new shortcut*, name your shortcut *Launch New Terminal* and add the command

```
gnome-terminal &
```

After the shortcut is added, highlight the newly-minted custom shortcut and press the unique key combination of your choice.

I personally use: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: that's correct, but I wonder what does the `&` part do?

Comment: Seems that sometimes `gnome-terminal &` doesn't work. I put `terminal &` instead and that worked.

Comment: The `&` is to specify that the command should run in the background. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13338895/1324082

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you use Gnome, check out `System / Preferences / Keyboard Shortcuts`.

Also, you can create a *launcher* to any application in any panel: either drag and drop an entry from the menu, or right click on an panel and click on `Add to panel`.

Answer (score 7):

## Add Terminal Shortcut in Debian 9 Stretch

1. Access **Keyboard Settings**.
   From top right → Down Arrow → Settings Icon → Keyboard

   From top left → Activities Tab → Search for 'shortcut' → Select Keyboard

   ---

   [image: Enter Debian Keyboard Shortcut Settings]
2. Scroll to the bottom of the Keyboard Shortcuts menu and click the "plus" sign ("+") to add new shortcut.

   ---

   [image: Click The Plus Sign To Add New Keyboard Shortcut in Debian 9 Stretch]
3. Add New Shortcut Name: `Name` (can be anything: "New Shell", "Launch Terminal", etc.)
   Add New Shortcut Command: `gnome-terminal`

   ---

   [image: Edit New Keyboard Shortcut Name & Command]
4. Then click "Edit" and it'll look like the screen freezes. This is your prompt to enter your new command.

   ---

   ### Press and hold the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

*The key combination auto-populates in the "New Shortcut" Tab.*

---

[image: Add Custom Keyboard Shortcut Keys in Debian 9 Stretch]


5. **Click ADD** in the top right corner to add your new shortcut to the main keyboard shortcut menu.

---

[image: Add New Shortcut to Keyboard Shortcut Menu in Debian 9 Stretch]

6. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (or whatever shortcut combination you entered) and the Terminal/Shell/Command Line pops up; shortcut created.

---

[image: Shortcut to Launch Terminal from Keyboard in Debian 9 Stretch]

References: [How to activate Debian hot-keys](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268451/how-to-activate-the-hotkeys-in-linux-debian-8-jessie-gnome-3-de)

Answer (score 1):

While this is *not* a keyboard shortcut, it works very well for me.

I just dragged my *Terminal* icon from the *Application / Utilities* menu to the *panel/status* line and stuck it there.

Now when I want to open a *terminal window*, it's a simple click on the icon.

*Eclipse* and my *browser live* on there too for easy access.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on terminal icon, go to preference and check the command field and copy it
2. Go to System > Control Center > Keyboard Shortcuts
3. Click on add and past the command and choose the shortcut that you want
   OS : Parrot

> In case you already deleted the Terminal shortcut by mistake, else you will find it by default.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on Debian 9. So here is my solution:

Go to `/usr/share/applications/`, scroll to the bottom, and find there `Xfce Terminal`. After you find everything copy the full path to it - `/usr/share/applications/Xfce Terminal`. Go to `Settings/Keyboard/Application Shourtcuts`, add new shourtcut, paste in to the input for the command the path to `Xfce Terminal` you copied before, and chose the shourtcut you want - i'm using `fn, f2`. It's all! I think it helped you!

Comment: Why is this more clear than the accepted answer by @deviantkarot  ??