# How to activate the hotkeys in Linux Debian 8 Jessie (Gnome 3 DE)?

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts

I installed the Linux Debian 8 OS with Gnome 3 Desktop Environment a couple of days ago; till then, I used Ubuntu on my PC and I always found really useful the hotkeys/shortcuts available in that distribution.

I noticed that Debian has not such hotkeys or, more probably, I did not installed those ones correctly or I don't know how to use these; for instance, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> does not open the *Terminal*.

I would like to have such shortcuts work because I find these ones really beneficial.

Browsing on the internet and UL, I did not find nothing useful.

Could some of you help me to find a solution?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the applications screen (move your mouse to the top-left corner), open Settings (type "settings" and click on the icon), then Keyboard, and click on the Shortcuts tab. This will show the currently-defined shortcuts, split up into categories. To add custom shortcuts:

1. click on the <kbd>+</kbd> button;
2. specify the name and command for your shortcut (*e.g.* "Terminal" and `x-terminal-emulator` or `gnome-terminal` for a terminal, depending on whether you want the default terminal emulator or specifically Gnome Terminal);
3. click on "Add", the new shortcut appears in the list;
4. click on "Disabled" to the right of the shortcut, and define the shortcut you want to use.