# how can I set a right click and open terminal in context menu

Tags: debian, shell, terminal, gnome-shell, user-interface

I am using Debian 10.1
See the following screenshot.
[image: right click and no terminal]
I am used to a Ubuntu environment where I do a right
 click and terminal opens. Is this kind of a thing possible for Debian environment. If it is possible please let me know 
how can I enable it?

If the same can be added to context menu like in the screenshot I see following three options
1)Change Background
2)Display Settings
3)Settings
Here can I add the option in black menu in screenshot to open terminal (I am not referring to the Ctrl+Alt+T to open terminal) some how tweaking gnome?

**edit**

based on discussion below 
package **gnome-tweak-tool** and **nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal**
were installed.
Then when required setting were not found as in videos here
1)https://youtu.be/scOYZZIyoM4
2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scOYZZIyoM4&feature=youtu.be
`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons`
has been set to true
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true`

Still the desired results have not been achieved.
What I want is I do a right click on any area on my desktop and in the context menu I want to see an option to open terminal.

Comment: Management of shortcuts/hotkeys is not related to your Linux flavor, but the desktop environment. As you seem to be running Gnome 3, take a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268451/how-to-activate-the-hotkeys-in-linux-debian-8-jessie-gnome-3-de) for hotkey management.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to activate the hotkeys in Linux Debian 8 Jessie (Gnome 3 DE)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268451/how-to-activate-the-hotkeys-in-linux-debian-8-jessie-gnome-3-de)

Comment: I want to  add the option to open terminal in black menu in screenshot to open terminal (I am not referring to the Ctrl+Alt+T to open terminal) some how tweaking gnome?

Comment: Please be more specific in future. Your fist question made hotkeys sound like a valuable option.

Answer (score 0):

Viewing your screenshot, you are using GNOME 3 (that is your DE, desktop environment, on top of Debian).
Here you can add *any* keyboard shortcut from GNOME's settings. You can find an useful page here **[1]**.

---

**[1]** [How to activate the hotkeys in Linux Debian 8 Jessie (Gnome 3 DE)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268451/how-to-activate-the-hotkeys-in-linux-debian-8-jessie-gnome-3-de)

Answer (score 0):

For this you will have to enable desktop icons. Install `Tweaks`

```
apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

And open it (called `Tweaks` in Activities -> Applications or via <kbd>ALT+F2</kbd> `gnome-tweaks`). Under `Desktop` activate `Show Icons`. Right click menu now should provide `Open Terminal`. If not, then you will also need to install `nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal`.

Comment: See this screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/13EDZKv0U4sjcrD1YFrS3cbUcBiTAnp1e/view?usp=sharing I don't  see Desktop any where as you mention. Did I miss something?

Comment: Very odd. Any "show (desktop) icons"-setting somewhere? Is `gnome-tweaks` also installed?

Comment: I have made a video for you, you can see it here https://youtu.be/scOYZZIyoM4 I had installed both gnome-tweak-tool and nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal see the video and you will understand better what I am asking.

Comment: OK, try the following: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons` (it should be "false") then set it to "true" via `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true`. You should now have the content of your home-dir on the desktop AND right-click should allow opening a terminal.

Comment: it did not worked commands I tried here is another video https://youtu.be/YrLw7ckA3Pk

Comment: Value of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons` after login/logout? (Tough password strength :D)

Comment: before logging in even before your command I tried it was  false, now after executing your command it is true that is where I had made video and after logging in and logging out also the values are true.

Comment: Just to be sure: `nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal` is installed? Desktop icons are managed by `nautilus`.

Comment: Yes the output of `debian@debian:~$ dpkg-query -l | grep nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal
ii  nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal      3.30.2-2                             amd64        GNOME terminal emulator application
debian@debian:~$ `