# How add Terminal Shortcut in Debian 9 Stretch Mate

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using Debian Stretch Mate and I want to open a terminal by using the keyboard shortcut 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. I tried the approaches given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268451/how-to-activate-the-hotkeys-in-linux-debian-8-jessie-gnome-3-de/268462) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41283/how-to-run-the-terminal-using-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gnome-2) but the don't work for me.

From [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268451/how-to-activate-the-hotkeys-in-linux-debian-8-jessie-gnome-3-de/268462)

Tell to does it

> From the applications screen (move your mouse to the top-left corner), open Settings (type "settings" and click on the icon)

But i have not "setting"...
Screenshot from my Desktop
[image]

With `apt-cache policy gnome`

to come

```
gnome:
Installiert:           (keine)
Installationskandidat: 1:3.22+3
Versionstabelle:
 1:3.22+3 500
    500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 Packages
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what you actually did. When you tried to follow [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268451/how-to-activate-the-hotkeys-in-linux-debian-8-jessie-gnome-3-de/268462), what happened? Did you not find the relevant setting? Did you find it but it didn't work? And no, Mate doesn't use Gnome2, Mate uses Mate. It is similar to gnome2 but different.

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! , maybe my problem ist that i have not Gnome ?

Comment: Yes, you're not using Gnome, you're using Mate. There must be a "Settings" app in Mate though. Either in the menu or on the top bar or both. Can't you find one?

Comment: I to search it , but not find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it...

My Mistake .. I to think that Mate und Gnome are one thing , but are Two , too Mate [working](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATE_(software)) with GNOME 2 ...

In System + Preferences + Hardware , is the keyboard Shortcuts
[image]

then , with **+ (Add)** , open a Window

[image]

and write , in **Name** , Terminal , in **Befehl**(command), gnome-terminal .

Then ,  with the Maus on Right Side(but sometimes on the Left side..., you try one , and when it not working , the another...) click on **Terminal** Line ,

[image]

and  give with the Keyboard , Ctrl Alt T ( I write Strg because my Kyboard is from germany...),then give on the Keyboard **↵ Enter**  ....

Answer (score 0):

It may not be *exactly* what you are looking for, but, on most desktop environments, even the ones with drop-down terminals, you can just use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to run 
 the command referring to the terminal you want to use (e.g. `xterm`, `mate-terminal`, etc.).

On the other hand, for MATE, apparently, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is enough to open a terminal window the easy way.

Comment: Thanks , with the First does Alt + F2 , then write , mate-terminal and come the Terminal , what it is not what i to want... With Second , this working on my Linux Mint with Mate.... but it not working on Debain Stretch Mate....