# Create keyboard shortcut in Arch [gnome]

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-shell

Im new to Arch and just installed it with gnome as a DE. I can run the gnome shell by clicking the icon but would like to setup a shortcut for it.
I'd like to setup the shortcut like in Ubuntu, `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T`.

Does anyone have any sujestions or can point me in the right direction?

### Edit:

I found you can ad a shortcut through ***Settings>Keyboard>View and Customise Shortcuts***. It asks for a command. What would would that command be? I'm trying to get it to open up at **/home**.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found Here: [How to run the terminal using keyboard shortcuts in Gnome 2?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41283/how-to-run-the-terminal-using-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gnome-2)

Command is `gnome-terminal &`